# Controlling a running VLC process via C++ in Windows

Tags: visual-c++, process, controls, vlc, libvlc

I want to control a running instance of VLC (not a server with rc) under windows. Is there any COM interface or other interface to do so? I've looked around but all I've figured out is few instances either mentioning [libvlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785829/vlc-remotely-control-from-c-sharp) or controlling it via [PostMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904447/controlling-vlc-mediamonkey-using-c).

I've seen some ActiveX examples too am I confusing something? Or is VLC not supporting any such thing?

**Modify**

Just want to re-emphasize I am looking for how to control a **already Running** VLC from my external process. Please do not post about libVLCWrapper its embedding into your application.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned yourself, libvlc is primary interface you have to control vlc. There are few wrappers around like following...

[utlibvlc](http://code.google.com/p/utlibvlc/)

[VLCWrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38952/VLCWrapper-A-Little-C-wrapper-Around-libvlc)

Comment: Any code snippet for playing pausing an already running VLC process? I am unable to find a function (in API) to attach libvlc_instance_t to a running VLC process.

Comment: VLCWrapper has play(), pause(), stop() etc functions, you can check out code. Even libvlc has attach and detach events, you can use these to attach to running process and then you can control it with other apis.

Comment: Thing you are referring to is for embedding VLC not doing an RPC or IPC over VLC.